# My laptop is making a horrible sound and vibrating

Tags: windows-10, laptop, fan

Okay, so this has been happening on and off for about two weeks. My computer will suddenly start literally vibrating and there is an awful buzzing sound. I have dual fans (it's a gaming laptop) and after troubleshooting I'm sure that it's my left fan. My computer does not crash, lag, freeze, or have any troubles besides the fan. I have done all I could to eliminate other possible problems -- I defragmented my hard drive and cleared up some space from it as well.

Today, I opened up my laptop and everything seemed to be perfectly fine. I assumed it was dust in the fans so I cleaned them out. After turning it on, it's still making that awful sound. It also occasionally makes a clicking noise. It's usable, but it's just so annoying and I hate dealing with it. Does anyone have any ideas about what might be happening with it? I will probably have to take it to the shop, but I just want an idea of what I might be dealing with here. Do you think the fan is catching on something? It doesn't seem like that would be the problem because when I blew the fan with air it spun fine and didn't seem ot catch on anything. Has anyone else dealt with this? My dad has been a computer engineer in the past and I'm probably going to look at it with him because he knows more than I do about hardware.

Comment: Just sounds like a bad fan. It can be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with my Sony Vaio, awful grinding noises. It was an hardware issue and fan module had to be replaced (luckily, it was still under guarantee). I'm afraid that's most probably your case and you'll have to send the computer for repairs.

Answer (score 0):

I have Sony Vaio, too and its doing the same thing. Making noise while I'm typing.

I'm using it for gaming and for school. Mine has an i5 with 6gb ram (it was 4 Gb ram and i3 but I upgraded it) and it works well for me.

On mine, the fan was the  problem. The laptop is 9 year old, still going very good after I upgraded. My fan was old and very dusty. If yours is new and doing this, just check if the fan is dusty .

Comment: 6gb is probably too little for gaming, at least for Windows. Upgrading processor and RAM puts more demand for cooling. 10 years for a laptop is multiple generations!

Answer (score -1):

Open Task manager and check resource usage of CPU/MEMORY/DISK. Make sure your laptop is not too hot.

Restart system in Safe Mode(starts system in a basic state), if problem persists, I would recommend you to contact the hardware supporter to have an detection.

**Start your PC in safe mode in Windows 10**:
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)